# Unable to display values in combo-box in ArcGIS Java Script API (ver 2.8)

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am trying to display few values in combo-box in JSAPI but I am getting an error ( I am not able to view the combo-box items).

I have attached my completed code in [JS-Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q2A4g/) (only removed server name)  and I searched on Google and put some alerts in that code so according to troubleshooting I found that problem is in “Store” (line no. 248 in populateList function ) and I think ESRI might updated  version 2.8 files hence getting this error.

Things that I have tried:

1. Inserted few alerts.
2. Tested it on 3 to 4 machines  (in IE, Firefox etc)
3. Contacted ESRI support but they told that its not their problem its dojo problem.
4. Want to update 3.3 versions but I think it is not support combo-box.

My application was working fine yesterday still wondering why this is happening…

I am confused now : (

Software's: AGIS DT & AGS ver.10.1 plus I am using query layer in AGIS DT 10.1

Any help will be great!!